# In Views, do filter criteria override context filters for the same field?

Tags: views

And can I do something about it?

I have a view that filters by date and exposes that filter to the user. I would like to be able to pass it in via the URL as well.

The accepted [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/18215/6073) to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18163/seo-friendly-views-how-do-i-make-contextual-filters-work-together-with-exposed) seems to indicate that this is not possible. True or not?

I could not find any docs on that question. Are there any?